# Will this PHP + postgreSQL code work? I'm coding blind!

Tags: php, json, postgresql

I have a strange question. I need to send some code to a client without having access to the server to test my code. In addition, it's using postgreSQL which I've never used, and I've not done PHP for a while!

In order to save some time, I'd really appreciate if someone could tell me if this code will do what I want?

#### example feed

```
<?
$sql = "SELECT * FROM V_SIDE_MENU_E";

include 'db.inc.php';
?>
```

#### db.inc.php

```
$connectString = 'host=localhost dbname=myDatabase user=foo password=bar';
$link = pg_connect($connectString);

if (!$link) {
    echo "error";
} else {

$result = pg_query($link, $sql);
$rows = array();
while($r = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would change

```
$rows = array();
while($r = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

into

```
print json_encode(array_values(pg_fetch_all($result)));
```

But that's just a style thing -- your code should work.

Comment: Many thanks Billy, that's good to know. Unfortunately I've just found out that the server the code is gonna run on is 5.1.6, which I understand doesn't have json_encode. But I found a __json_encode function in the comments here which sounds like it should work for me: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @Marky: Tell whoever's running the server to update their copy of PHP. 5.1.6 is riddled with holes. You should be able to get `json_encode` by installing a PECL extension on PHP < 5.2.

Answer (score 2):

Tested on your mysql ( it looks like it will work ). Your SELECT will work same in PostgreSQL like mySQL